# List of abstract base class only return properties from base class

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a model setup similar to this.
Two Classes inheriting from an abstract base class.

```
// Models
public abstract class Transaction 
{
    // Shared Properties..
}
public class TransactionType1 : Transaction
{
    public int TxType1Prop { get; set;}
}
public class TransactionType2 : Transaction
{
    public int TxType2Prop { get; set;}
}
```

In my API I have a List of 'base class' Where i Populate it with the different transactiontypes.
When I debug right before returning everything looks good the individual properties is populated etc..

```
// Ctrl
public IAtionResult GetTransactions()
{
    var transactions = new list<Transaction>() 
    {
        new TransactionType1(),
        new TransactionType2() 
    }
    return Ok(transactions);
}
```

But when the Api call is returned to swagger only the shared properties from the base class is included.

IE `TxType1Prop` & `TxType2Prop` are not included in the result.

Is it only possible to work with those properties in memory or can I get my result to include them as well?

Comment: Switch to using json.net, the .NET Core json classes are ... finicky ... when it comes to inheritance. Yes, they're fast, but the speed comes at a cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not use common base classes at interfaces with the "out of box" serializer *[This is for the "out of box" setup - as Ben mentioned, there are ways around it]*. You can provide a custom JSON serializer that might be able to handle this. In my option, even when it's working it's not the cleanest solution because:

1. You are exposing internal information about your app (like the serializer)
2. You enlarge your JSON
3. You decrease readability
4. APIs are about contracts, polymorphism breaks this to some degree

You can read more about polymorphism at APIs [here](https://leanpub.com/yourapiisbad/read#leanpub-auto-requests-and-responses).

The best approach, in my opinion, would be to use another type of class as a transport object which consists of the main attributes and an additional key-value set of "extra properties" (the sub-classes properties) with this approach, you can send all information needed (maybe you like to add type information for easier handling on the client-side).

```
public class TransactionTransport {
   // other attributes ommited

   // attribute name / attribute value
   Map<String, Object> AdditionalValues {get; set;}
}
```

In this case, you need to fill `AdditionalValues` with the attributes of the sub-classes in your API (map the sub-classes to `TransactionTransport`) and you are good to go.

This will also slightly decrease the readability but with a lot less unneeded content in the JSON. Furthermore, you are not exposing anything internal to the open wild.

Comment: JSON parsers definitely can and do support polymorphism.

Comment: For example see https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm

Comment: You are right that it's possible but in my option not desirable, I edited the answer. Furthermore, you'd expose a lot of internals to the open world which is quite problematic in my opinion.

Comment: To avoid sending your internal classnames, you can implement a custom JsonConverter that uses any rule of your choice to decide what actual type to instantiate.  I've done this and it's a lot less work than manually copying every derived class field to/from a dictionary like that.

Comment: Yes im not really interested in copying or creating DTO's for this purpose here atleast. Above was mean as simple illiustration.
Provided solution works perfect! Ill just accept this and give Ben a couple of thumbs here. 
Thanks to you both! good night